# How to simulate AWS Dynamodb outage within one availability zone

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-dynamodb, availability-zone

I want to test my dynamodb with one availability zone failure.
The basic idea comes to my mind is that find out EC2 instance(s) which dynamodb is running on within an availability zone, and stop or terminated it/them or do something in security group or NACL that related to the EC2 instance(s). 
But I am even not found the EC2 instance that running dynamodb in my AWS account. 
Any idea is welcome!!!

Answer (score 0):

DynamoDB doesn't run on EC2 instances in your account. Like for example S3 it's a AWS-managed service running on hardware outside of your account. Because of that you can't test partial failures of DynamoDB, because you have no possibility to induce such failures into DynamoDB.

Comment: Thanks a lot, it saves me a lot of time.

Comment: Do you have any referenced document or link that talk the detail?